# How to use Nix to build software that uses time.h on macOS

Tags: c, macos, nix

I have some software written in C. It compiles fine, but when I try to package it as a Nix package, the compiler emits the error

> unknown type name 'clockid_t'; did you mean 'clock_t'?

Here is a MCVE:

default.nix:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "asdf";
  src = lib.cleanSource ./.;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

clockid_t x;

int main() { return 0; }
```

makefile:

```
all:
    cc main.c -o main
```

Putting these files in a directory and executing `nix-build` produces this output:

```
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/8djs648bj3bqrn0bz51hmf79wdifks2b-asdf.drv
building '/nix/store/8djs648bj3bqrn0bz51hmf79wdifks2b-asdf.drv'...
unpacking sources
unpacking source archive /nix/store/zm8c46i44hp2gr9gc7n41f3vg02jh2v5-asdf
source root is asdf
patching sources
configuring
no configure script, doing nothing
building
build flags: SHELL=/nix/store/g9cis4hsnzcjkzfa77nif7kzq9bsqmpg-bash-4.4-p23/bin/bash
cc main.c -o main
main.c:4:1: error: unknown type name 'clockid_t'; did you mean 'clock_t'?
clockid_t x;
^~~~~~~~~
clock_t
/nix/store/l77bg1s15f0wgjf4c12fc29ghvjbswwy-Libsystem-osx-10.11.6/include/sys/_types/_clock_t.h:30:33: note: 'clock_t' declared here
typedef __darwin_clock_t        clock_t;
                                ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [makefile:2: all] Error 1
builder for '/nix/store/8djs648bj3bqrn0bz51hmf79wdifks2b-asdf.drv' failed with exit code 2
error: build of '/nix/store/8djs648bj3bqrn0bz51hmf79wdifks2b-asdf.drv' failed
```

But when I simply run `make` there is no error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a compile error that was fixed in OS X since 10.11.6 that you're using in your derivation.

Upgrading to a newer nixpkgs should solve the issue. Nixpkgs 18.09 should be sufficient.

Comment: I'm using OS X 10.13 and nixpkgs 19.09.